# R recursive function nested too deeply

Tags: r, function, recursion

I have this recursive function and I am trying to find the result when `x(n) = 1000`.

```
x <- function (n) if (n==1) 1 else {(13*Recall(n - 1) + 7) %% 112233}
```

I can use this code when `n < 600` or something but when `n > 600` I get

> "evaluation nested too deeply: 
>   infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?".

How should I change the code to calculate `x(1000)`?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK GNU-R uses c's call stack, so it's not that well suited for lengthy recursions. You'd probably get better with iterative version:

```
x2 <- function(n) {
 acc <- 1;
 m <- 1;
 repeat {
   acc <- (13*acc+7) %% 112233
   m <- m+1
   if (m>=n) break
 }
 acc
}
```

e.g.

```
> x2(600)
[1] 67812
> x2(1000)
[1] 9292
```